# php artisan route:cache shows Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization. Uses Closure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, deployment, php-7.2

When I run '`php artisan route:cache`' on production server, it shows

> In Route.php line 880: Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization.
>   Uses Closure.

How to solve that??

Comment: Don't use a closure

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Create a controller that does what your closure does and use that controller in your route file

Comment: <?php

Route::prefix('api')->group(function(){

Comment: ???? That doesn't look like the `route [/]` mentioned. It's probably in `routes/web.php` ... `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});`

Comment: I am using laravel package

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes/web.php` file there's a "default" route created by Laravel:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Run `php artisan make:controller WelcomeController` to create a new controller and use this controller in your route file instead of the closure:

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

Your `WelcomeController` should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad it works. Please accept this as an answer.